# xml parsing from dom list to an xml file

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, dom

I wanted to put some data into an existing xml file and I really like the idea of the DOM Parser. I came across this example http://java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=152 and it doesn't show how to turn the list back to a XML file so my question is how to make a xml file from a list like the one in that example.

P.S if you have a different or better way to parse xml files or add data to them I would love a reference to a tutorial or something. I program using android studio and Java.

Comment: Quite some info about XML parsing/quering/creating/modifying with different parsers (dom, jdom, dom4j, sax, stax, xpath) here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/index.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can check this link for XML parsing which include
Read a XML file

Modify existing XML file

Create a new XML file

Count XML Elements

http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/java-xml-tutorials/